# Defining and passing arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to pass the arguments

```
->,line width=1.2pt
```

to command

```
\draw [] ...
```

However, this does not work

```
\newcommand\newstyle{->,line width=1.2pt}
\draw[\newstyle]
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tikz options are not handled that way; if you pass a macro to `\draw`, it will think you meant to call a single key with the name `->,line width=1.2pt`.  Instead, use a real style:

```
\tikzset{newstyle/.style = {->,line width=1.2pt}}
\draw[newstyle] ...
```